# Hash Table в Delphi

Tags: delphi-7, хеширование

Пожалуйста, дайте пример кода hashtable для Delphi 7 (нет generic-ов).

Надо хранить и самое важное **быстро искать** пару ключ-значение, где и то и то - строки различной длины.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это явно работа за автора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Подобный вопрос был на стэке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179162/hashtable-implementation-for-delphi-5)
Так же, если погуглить, то можно найти много чего:
 1. [Описание класса Hashtable](http://study-programming.ru/java/java/klass-hashtable.html)
 2. [библиотека GsvHashTable](http://gurin.tomsknet.ru/delphihashtable.html) (не знаю, опен сорс или нет)

PS. Поиск ответа на данный вопрос в интернетах занимает меньше времени, чем написание вопроса на данном ресурсе. И не говорите, что у вас гугл забанен. Его еще вчера достали из списка блокируемых.

Comment: Нет, гугл не забанен. Как я и писал выше, я прочел достаточное количество информации по теме. С теорией прекрасно ознакомлен. Практика же была изложена отвратительно. Сейчас посмотрю ваши ссылки

Comment: Действительно на стэке неплохое обсуждение и куча полезных ссылок по теме, среди которых самое близкое к моей задаче вот это:

http://omnithreadlibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/GpStringHash.pas

Благодарю за наводку

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая реализация в QStrings (Delphi7) **AcedContainers** 1.17

Классы и коллекции для организации битовых полей,обычных, ассоциативных, связанных, хэшированных и других списков, бинарных деревьев, обычных и приоритетных очередей и т.п.